# Is it possible to display single value in graphite?

Tags: graphite

I'd like to display a moving average as a number not as a graph.

Is it possible to display a number in graphite?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all graph data by adding param `format=json` to the url. It is not a single value, but it is the only way. Example

This will render png graph

> http://graphite.loc/render?from=-1minutes&until=now&width=400&height=250&target=movingAverage%28carbon.relays.local.connections%2C10%29&title=movingAverage%28carbon.relays.local.connections%2C2%29

but with format=json

> http://graphite.loc/render?from=-1minutes&until=now&width=400&height=250&target=movingAverage%28carbon.relays.local.connections%2C10%29&title=movingAverage%28carbon.relays.local.connections%2C2%29**&format=json**`

it will output json with target name, datapoints (values with timestamp)

```
[{"target": "movingAverage(carbon.relays.localhost.connections,10)", "datapoints": [[154069.8, 1452992400]]}]
```